# fetching data from JSON cannot work with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I intend to fecthing data from JSON with ajax to html with append, and its work really good. But I'm having a problem when I trying to load html from external file, the variable cannot read with jquery load.

How I can read the variable from external file with jquery load to show in HTML?

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'person.json',
    dataType:'json',
    type:'get',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        $(data.person).each(function(index, value){
            //$("#loadJson").append('<p><strong>Name : </strong>'+value.first_name+'</br><strong>Company: </strong>'+value.company+'</br> <strong>Email: </strong>'+value.email+' </p>')
            $("#loadJson").load('data.html');
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<p><strong>Name: </strong>'+value.first_name+'</br><strong>Company: </strong>'+value.company+'</br> <strong>Email: </strong>'+value.email+' </p>
```

Comment: please check the path

Answer (score 0):

You can load html as a template for the js variable, stick with appending build html

```
success:function(data){
            $(data.person).each(function(index, value){
                $("#loadJson").append('<p><strong>Name : </strong>'+value.first_name+'</br><strong>Company: </strong>'+value.company+'</br> <strong>Email: </strong>'+value.email+' </p>');
            });

        }
```

or use a templating framework/engine

Answer (score 0):

1- have you checked the path? Make sure it is working.

2- are you sure the response type is json? If not, try this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
// bind data here
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, because I store in same dir